# I edited some CSS, and now my page is weirdly twice as wide

Tags: css, scroll, padding

I'm using a preset portfolio service called Cargo Collective.

I edited the top padding for the navigation window so that the header wouldn't cover it.

The page now is twice as wide, and has an h-scroll bar now at any reasonable browser width.

I searched through the px padding in the css, however there's nothing glaringly obvious. My conclusion is that something is repeating the 670px width over twice.

Here's a link to the page:

http://cargocollective.com/BrookesEggleston

Here's the code from this section:

```
/*
 * Header / Navigation
 */

.header_img {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px; top: 20px;
    z-index: 15;
}

.nav_container {
    background: #ffffff;
    line-height: 1.8;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 50px 0 20px 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 198px; left: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 190px;
    z-index: 12;
}

/* Enabled via Display Options */
.nav_container.horizontal {
    left: auto;
    padding: 35px 0 60px 35px;
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    width: 670px;
    z-index: 25;
}

.nav_container.horizontal div {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#nav_loadspin {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 37px; left: 40px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the header CSS to:

```
.header_img {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
    z-index: 15;
}
```

As you're positioning the header with `left` (rather than with `padding`), the body's width essentially becomes 100% + 20px. This will create a horizontal scroll regardless of the browser size.

Changing the `left` position to true `padding` fixed it for me in Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is where the problem is coming from:

Change the `left` on `.header_img`

```
.header_img {
position: relative;
left: 20px; top: 20px;
z-index: 15;
```

To `padding-left`

```
.header_img {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20px; top: 20px;
    z-index: 15;
```